Which exception is thrown by DataStoreRepository is there's time out or downtime?
I want to implement exponential back off for some errors which appear rarely due to some downtimes in GCP Datastore. My idea is to use @Retryable but I want to catch only the exception related to the timeouts or connection errors (5XX).
Do you know which exception would cover this? Catching all RuntimeExceptions was my first though but that's too broad, hence, a bad idea.
I'm doing queries through com.google.cloud.spring.data.datastore.repository.DatastoreRepository
Because this is a rare error, I have no logs at hand to check for clues. I've been researching and I found the DataAccessException is a generic RuntimeException which covers must Spring Data errors but I think I need something more fined grained.

DatastoreRepository returns DatastoreException for any runtime exception. This exception covers multiple errors that are described here.
So what's important is the error code and the reason, the DatastoreException class already defines which error types are retryable:
private static final Set<Error> RETRYABLE_ERRORS =
  ImmutableSet.of(
      new Error(10, "ABORTED", false),
      new Error(4, "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED", false),
      new Error(14, "UNAVAILABLE", true));

As you can see, you don't have direct access to those. So to be able to validate if a retryable error was thrown use the isReatryable() method in the exception.
So in my case I validated this within a RetryListener, if is not retryable I simply interrupt the retry attempts:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DatastoreExceptionListener implements RetryListener {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof DatastoreException ex) {
            log.error("Retry count: {} | Datastore Exception: {} - {} | Error location: {}",
                    context.getRetryCount(), ex.getCode(), ex.getReason(), context.getAttribute("context.name"));
            if (!ex.isRetryable()) {
                log.error("Non retryable DatastoreException, no further retries will be attempted");
                context.setExhaustedOnly();
            }
        }
        RetryListener.super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }
}

